# Symfony2.1 - HWIOAuthBundle and google oauth authentication

Tags: authentication, symfony, oauth-2.0, symfony-2.1, hwioauthbundle

I am trying to setup Symfony2.1 with [HWIOAuthBundle](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) to handle google oauth authentication.

I have followed manual instructions in bundle description, but still something is missing. When I visit an action which requires authenticated user (or just type url /connect/google) I am redirected to google authentication page - this part is working. But after redirection back (after logging to Google and agree for sharing my data) new user is not created in DB and I am redirected into connect/fail action. Google authentication should be only one way to authenticate user. Any idea what could be wrong?

This is my routing:

```
hwi_oauth_redirect:
    resource: "@HWIOAuthBundle/Resources/config/routing/redirect.xml"
    prefix:   /connect

google_login:
    pattern: /login/check-google
```

security.yml

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /connect/google
            check_path: /login/login_check
        logout: true
        anonymous: true
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                google: "/login/check-google"
            login_path:        /connect/google
            failure_path:      /connect-fail
            # FOSUB integration
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
```

and config

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_name: secured_area
    resource_owners:
            google:
                type:                google
                client_id:           ....
                client_secret:       ......
                scope:               "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
    fosub:
        username_iterations: 5
        properties:
            google: googleId
```

google redirectURL

```
http://xxxx/login/check-google
```

my User entity:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="google_id", type="integer")
     */ 
    protected $googleId;
```

//edit- update

I just found in Symfony logs that I had one request from google redirect:
GET http://xxxxx.dk/login/check-google?code=4%2F8tiDAhI45D2g7BvrdtwoF7wJ.Eu7i2fmkYOl05ti8ZT3YDrXXXXXfakeXXXE4hcwI just before redirect to /connect-file
Unfortunately it looks that request only tried to retrieve user from my db based on google_id 
SELECT * FROM app_user t0 WHERE t0.googleId = ? LIMIT  1 : ['123456789']  but that user does not exist there.

Should I create user befor I tryied to authenticate him/her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, HWIOAuthBundle doesn't handle automatic registration by default. If you want to login now you'll have to create the user manually.

Answer (score 6):

As [beliveyourdream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682619/beliveyourdream) says... HWIOAuth does NOT provide you automatic user registration. You need to create your own user provider and use that. I suggest you go with [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle) as it does most of the job and it is pretty well integrated in HWIOAuth. For how to set up (as it is a bit of work to do on connecting them), please use this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/4476697). It does setup your application with both user registration using data from PROVIDERS (gacebook, google, github, etc.) and account connection (an already registered user may connect his/her account with accouns from PROVIDERS). Also, upon creation/connection, the users will be able to connect to your site with the PROVIDERS' credentials (duh... it's OAuth, after all).